# Building package using RcppArmadillo on 64bit Windows

Tags: r, rcpp

I have been using RcppArmadillo to build a package, but I've run into a small problem. I have a perfectly working package for 32-bit R, but I would like for it to run on 64-bit. When I started working on the package I was using 32-bit R (without realizing it), but when I shifted to 64-bit R I stopped being able to build my package. I get the error saying "LoadLibrary failure: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

I realize that the issue is that the .dll file is 32-bit so 64-bit R can't work with it. What I don't understand is how to recreate the .dll so that it is 64-bit. In 64-bit R when I run `devtools::find_rtools()` I get TRUE, so I suspect that I have to add something to the makevars files to make this work.

So my question in one sentence is: how do you get a working 32bit package with RcppArmadillo to work with 64bit on Windows? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*All* CRAN packages build on 32 and 64 bit Windows.

*All* CRAN submissions, including my different Rcpp* packages do (apart from those requiring Unix, or C++11, or ...).

So if I were you, and had (temporary) troubles setting up my main box, I would still use the excellent [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org) which will generate 32 and 64 bit binaries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, it was the makevars files.

I had to add `$(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()")`

Comment: No, you do not need `Rcpp::LdFlags()` anymore unless you are using a two-year old Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dirk. I was able to build the package without `Rcpp::LdFlags()` by adding `--force-biarch` to `R CMD INSTALL`